# Maintain similar image size in PDF using itextsharp

Tags: c#, asp.net, itext

i'm using itextsharp to bring my picture over to the pdf file. I uses chunk. However when i uses  the chunk new line, my image changes it size despite me putting the same scaletofit.

[image]

```
protected void btnPDF_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        var doc1 = new Document();
        var filename = "MyTestPDF" + DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyyMMddHHmmssfff") + ".pdf";
        var output = new FileStream(Path.Combine("C:\\Users\\apr13mpsip\\Downloads", filename), FileMode.Create);
        iTextSharp.text.pdf.PdfWriter.GetInstance(doc1, output);
        doc1.Open();


        PdfPTable table = new PdfPTable(1);

        table.TotalWidth = 585f;
        table.LockedWidth = true;


        PdfPTable table2 = new PdfPTable(1);
        table2.TotalWidth = 585f;
        table2.LockedWidth = true;

        iTextSharp.text.pdf.PdfPCell imgCell1 = new iTextSharp.text.pdf.PdfPCell();

        var logo = iTextSharp.text.Image.GetInstance(Server.MapPath("~/image/logo.jpg"));
        doc1.Add(logo);

        var titleFont = FontFactory.GetFont("Arial", 15, Font.BOLD);
        doc1.Add(new Paragraph("Official Report. Member Report ID : " + DDLCase.SelectedValue, titleFont));

        var normalFont = FontFactory.GetFont(FontFactory.HELVETICA, 14, Font.BOLD);
        var phrase = new Phrase();
        var phrase2 = new Phrase();

        SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection("Data Source = localhost; Initial Catalog = project; Integrated Security = SSPI");

        SqlCommand cm = new SqlCommand("Select lro.fullname, lro.contact, mr.typeofcrime, mr.location,mr.crdatetime, mr.citizenreport, pr.policeid,  pr.prdatetime, pr.policereport, aor.officialreport,  mr.image1, mr.image2, mr.image3, mr.image4, mr.image5,  pr.image1, pr.image2, pr.image3, pr.image4, pr.image5 from MemberReport mr, PoliceReport pr, LoginRegisterOthers lro, AdminOfficialReport aor where mr.memberreportid = '" + DDLCase.SelectedValue + "' and mr.memberreportid=pr.memberreportid and pr.policereportid=aor.policereportid", con);
        con.Open();
        SqlDataReader dr;

        dr = cm.ExecuteReader();

        if (dr.Read())
        {


            phrase2.Add(new Chunk("Citizen Images :", normalFont));

            phrase2.Add(Chunk.NEWLINE);
            phrase2.Add(Chunk.NEWLINE);
            phrase2.Add(Chunk.NEWLINE);
            phrase2.Add(Chunk.NEWLINE);
            phrase2.Add(Chunk.NEWLINE);

            phrase2.Add(new Chunk("1.", normalFont));
            Byte[] bytes1 = (Byte[])dr[10];
            iTextSharp.text.Image image1 = iTextSharp.text.Image.GetInstance(bytes1);
            image1.ScaleToFit(750f, 750f);
            Chunk imageChunk1 = new Chunk(image1, 0, -30);
            phrase2.Add(imageChunk1);

            phrase2.Add(Chunk.NEWLINE);
            phrase2.Add(Chunk.NEWLINE);
            phrase2.Add(Chunk.NEWLINE);
            phrase2.Add(Chunk.NEWLINE);
            phrase2.Add(Chunk.NEWLINE);


            phrase2.Add(new Chunk("2.", normalFont));
            Byte[] bytes5 = (Byte[])dr[11];
            iTextSharp.text.Image image5 = iTextSharp.text.Image.GetInstance(bytes5);
            image5.ScaleToFit(750f, 750f);
            Chunk imageChunk5 = new Chunk(image5, 0, -30);
            phrase2.Add(imageChunk5);

            phrase2.Add(Chunk.NEWLINE);
            phrase2.Add(Chunk.NEWLINE);
            phrase2.Add(Chunk.NEWLINE);
            phrase2.Add(Chunk.NEWLINE);
            phrase2.Add(Chunk.NEWLINE);

            phrase2.Add(new Chunk("3.", normalFont));
            Byte[] bytes6 = (Byte[])dr[12];
            iTextSharp.text.Image image6 = iTextSharp.text.Image.GetInstance(bytes6);
            image6.ScaleToFit(750f, 750f);
            Chunk imageChunk6 = new Chunk(image6, 0, -30);
            phrase2.Add(imageChunk6);

            phrase2.Add(Chunk.NEWLINE);
            phrase2.Add(Chunk.NEWLINE);
            phrase2.Add(Chunk.NEWLINE);
            phrase2.Add(Chunk.NEWLINE);
            phrase2.Add(Chunk.NEWLINE);


            phrase2.Add(new Chunk("4.", normalFont));
            Byte[] bytes7 = (Byte[])dr[13];
            iTextSharp.text.Image image7 = iTextSharp.text.Image.GetInstance(bytes7);
            image7.ScaleToFit(750f, 750f);
            Chunk imageChunk7 = new Chunk(image7, 0, -30);
            phrase2.Add(imageChunk7);

            phrase2.Add(Chunk.NEWLINE);
            phrase2.Add(Chunk.NEWLINE);
            phrase2.Add(Chunk.NEWLINE);
            phrase2.Add(Chunk.NEWLINE);
            phrase2.Add(Chunk.NEWLINE);

            phrase2.Add(new Chunk("5.", normalFont));
            Byte[] bytes8 = (Byte[])dr[14];
            iTextSharp.text.Image image8 = iTextSharp.text.Image.GetInstance(bytes8);
            image8.ScaleToFit(750f, 750f);
            Chunk imageChunk8 = new Chunk(image8, 0, -30);
            phrase2.Add(imageChunk8);

            phrase2.Add(Chunk.NEWLINE);
            phrase2.Add(Chunk.NEWLINE);
            phrase2.Add(Chunk.NEWLINE);
            phrase2.Add(Chunk.NEWLINE);


            table2.AddCell(phrase2);

        }

        dr.Close();
        doc1.Add(table);
        doc1.NewPage();
        doc1.Add(table2);
        doc1.Close();
    }


}
```

Comment: This was a bug in some old iTextSharp versions; it should have been fixed by now. If you don't mention which version you're using, you shouldn't expect an answer because your code will work correctly for many people.

Comment: May i know how to check which version of itextsharp am i using? And how do i get the latest version of itextsharp? It's my first time using itextsharp though.

Comment: Check the producer line of your PDF. Latest version: http://sourceforge.net/projects/itextsharp/files/itextsharp/

Comment: i'm already using one of the latest iTextSharp version of 5.4.1.

Comment: I downloaded the latest version of iTextSharp but i still get the same problem :/

Comment: Then we'll have to file a bug report.

Comment: May i know how to send a bug report? I need this to be done real badly as my project require the pictures to be aligned properly in the pdf. I searched all over the net for over a week or two. However i failed to get the pdf file this is proper working condition.

Comment: Bug reports only get priority when you're a paying customer. I've created a ticket on the paid support ticketing system, but priority is low. The fix may or may not be in the next release scheduled for the last week of July.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I completely forgot about this question, but I'll answer it now for further reference. iTextSharp resizes images automatically (which is what you'd want in most cases), but you can avoid this by setting `ScaleToFitHeight = false` to each image.

```
phrase2.Add(new Chunk("1.", normalFont));
Byte[] bytes1 = (Byte[])dr[10];
iTextSharp.text.Image image1 = iTextSharp.text.Image.GetInstance(bytes1);
image1.ScaleToFit(750f, 750f);
//set scale to fit height = false
image1.ScaleToFitHeight = false;
Chunk imageChunk1 = new Chunk(image1, 0, -30);
phrase2.Add(imageChunk1);
```

Comment: It's okay sir. Actually, I've finished my major project that uses itextsharp. However I will still sincerely thank you for your help and  will use the information above as a reference for future purposes :)

Comment: @TeoChuenWeiBryan upvote Bruno's answer and mark it as correct.