# iTextSharp Image minimum Table cell height

Tags: c#, asp.net, image, width, itext

I am trying to append images to a PDF document, but the image width must = `doc.PageSize.Width` and height in ratio with the image width.

I am appending individual images, each in its own table and in a cell using the following method

```
public void AddImage(Document doc, iTextSharp.text.Image Image)
{
    PdfPTable table = new PdfPTable(1);
    table.WidthPercentage = 100;
    table.TotalWidth = doc.PageSize.Width;

    PdfPCell c = new PdfPCell(Image, true);
    c.Border = PdfPCell.NO_BORDER;
    c.Padding = 5;
    c.FixedHeight = (doc.PageSize.Width / Image.Width) * Image.Height;
    c.MinimumHeight = (doc.PageSize.Width / Image.Width) * Image.Height;

    table.AddCell(c);

    doc.Add(table);
}
```

The Document code part (Do not think this is necessary though):

```
using (PDFBuilder pdf = new PDFBuilder())
{
    using (var doc = new Document())
    {
        PdfWriter writer = PdfWriter.GetInstance(doc, Response.OutputStream);
        doc.Open();
        var image = iTextSharp.text.Image.GetInstance(Request.MapPath("~/Images/Nemo.jpg"));
        pdf.AddImage(doc, image);
        pdf.AddImage(doc, image);
        pdf.AddImage(doc, image);
    }
}
```

What I want is for the images to be 100% width, and if not, the image must append on the next page.

**This is currently what I am getting**

[image]

**And this is what I want**

[image]

Any help would be greatly appreciated, thank you in advance**!**

Comment: Which version of iTextSharp are you using? I know that this was fixed and answered on StackOverflow, but I can't find the link right away.

Comment: @BrunoLowagie I am not sure where to look for the Version, but in VS `Version = 5.4.5.0` on `.net 2.0`, Post the link as the answer - I will mark it as the correct answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Got It!

This line needed to be added:

```
c.Image.ScaleToFitHeight = false;
```

My Method

```
public void AddImage(Document doc, iTextSharp.text.Image Image)
{
    PdfPTable table = new PdfPTable(1);
    table.WidthPercentage = 100;

    PdfPCell c = new PdfPCell(Image, true);
    c.Border = PdfPCell.NO_BORDER;
    c.Padding = 5;
    c.Image.ScaleToFitHeight = false; /*The new line*/

    table.AddCell(c);

    doc.Add(table);
}
```

Comment: Yes, I was looking for it, and I also just found it: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17336499/maintain-similiar-image-size-in-pdf-using-itextsharp (I hard a hard time finding it because the question dated from June and I was looking for questions asked in the last couple of months). In any case: I upvoted your answer.

Comment: Thank you for all your efforts!